# How to change color of the spinner for cursor: progress/wait CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Is there a way to change the default blue spinner for `cursor: progress` in CSS? If not, how would one render an animated loading cursor in react?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom cursor with svg or png.
`cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), auto;`